# Detect XP,Vista, or Windows 7 and select XAML style depending on version of OS

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

So I've been testing my styles on different versions of Windows with the same resolution. Most control styles look the same but others are a bit off. I want to create seperate styles for different versions of windows. Similar to the CSS/html technique where you create CSS files for different browers. I'm just curious if this is a good way on handling this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I can tell you how to detect which version of windows but not sure if thats the right way to do it

Comment: The way you choose is not good. May be you can provide us with an example, and show what exactly you want to style another way for one OS.

Answer (score 0):

May be the thing you need - not styles but [Theme](http://wpftutorial.net/Themes.html)? I would recommend you reading excellent book about WPF: Adam Nathan "WPF Unleashed". There is chapter about styling and theming.

Comment: So do I use themes for different OS's? I would still need to know how to detect the version of windows.